# ![Billing hard has been reached] open ai

Tags: api, openai-api

![Billing hard has been reached]
I was working with open Ai API and got this error although I have 18 credits in my account. can someone help me out??

everything is working fine on req to api getting limit reached as error .** i have checked my account its a fresh one with 18 credits remaining as balance**